# PayPal SDK with TypeScript - paypal.Buttons() is possibly undefined?

Tags: typescript, paypal

I'm using the PayPal SDK in my SvelteKit app, using TypeScript. I'm running into the issue where running their `paypal.Buttons` method like documented always results in a TypeScript error.

For example this is the code from their [README](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-js):

```
import { loadScript } from "@paypal/paypal-js";

let paypal;

try {
  paypal = await loadScript({ clientId: "test" });
} catch (error) {
  console.error("failed to load the PayPal JS SDK script", error);
}

if (paypal) {
  try {
    await paypal.Buttons().render("#your-container-element");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("failed to render the PayPal Buttons", error);
  }
}
```

But this gives the error `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly undefined` on line 13, on `paypal.Buttons()`. How can I call their method without having this error always show up in my linter's output? I don't know if their README needs to be updated, or if their code needs to be fixed to return better types?

Comment: Not familiar with the PayPal SDK. But sounds like an optional chaining operator (`paypal.Buttons?.()`) should to the trick.

Comment: But it's `paypal.Buttons` itself that is possibly undefined, and I can't do `await paypal.Buttons?().render("#your-container-element")` because that's not valid TS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing any debugging details or further specific typings in the PayPayl SDK, using optional chaining as follows works perfectly fine. Pay attention to the syntax: `?.()`.

```
type Paypal = {
  Buttons?(): {render(): any};
};

const paypal: Paypal = {
  Buttons() {
    return {render() {}};
  }
};

paypal.Buttons?.().render();
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghuOAbKBeKBvAsAKClAIQFdhgB7AOwGcB%20ACgEoAuTAJwgoBMJXGW4KIAL4BuXKNy4AxpSrAoYBIqQt4iFOmx5CJctUaZc%20fO2BFWFNh268GmIRO1DxYnLkXqAdMVKyanxk92Lh5GVyA)

---

Take a look at the compiled JS output.

```
"use strict";
var _a;
const paypal = {
    Buttons() {
        return { render() { } };
    }
};
(_a = paypal.Buttons) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.call(paypal).render();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think their types don't really make sense.

```
export interface PayPalNamespace {
    Buttons?: (
        options?: PayPalButtonsComponentOptions,
    ) => PayPalButtonsComponent;
    Marks?: (options?: PayPalMarksComponentOptions) => PayPalMarksComponent;
    Messages?: (
        options?: PayPalMessagesComponentOptions,
    ) => PayPalMessagesComponent;
    HostedFields?: PayPalHostedFieldsComponent;
    getFundingSources?: getFundingSources;
    isFundingEligible?: isFundingEligible;
    rememberFunding?: rememberFunding;
    FUNDING?: Record<string, FUNDING_SOURCE>;
    version: string;
}
```

Like, why is Buttons optional?

But anyway, found a simple workaround to make the error go away:

```
if (paypal && paypal.Buttons) {
  try {
    await paypal.Buttons().render("#your-container-element");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("failed to render the PayPal Buttons", error);
  }
}
```